# The member ScreenShot of type System.Drawing.Bitmap cannot be used as a parameter value

Tags: c#, ssms

I have pretty much exhausted all of my knowledge up to this point, I keep getting an error on VS 2019:
(System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The member ScreenShot of type System.Drawing.Bitmap cannot be used as a parameter value
  Source=Dapper)
I am attempting to save a screenshot to a SQL database, I have created a stored procedure to save it to the table. 
I understand that I need to convert it from bitmap to binary and its being stored in SQL as varbinary(MAX). I just do not know where I need to place that conversion. Perhaps, that is not even the issue here. I greatly appreciate any advice, and thank you all ahead of time.

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig2.CnnString("REPORTSSQL")))
{              
  var P = new DynamicParameters();
  P.Add("UserName", model.UserName);
  P.Add("EmailAddress", model.EmailAddress);
  P.Add("PhoneNumber", model.PhoneNumber);
  P.Add("CommentBox", model.CommentBox);
  P.Add("CreateDate", model.CreateDate);
  P.Add("ScreenShot", model.ScreenShot);
  P.Add("Id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
  model.ScreenShot = P.Get<Image>("@ScreenShot");

  connection.Execute("dbo.spInterReportTable_Insert1", P, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

  model.Id = P.Get<int>("@Id");

  return model;
}
```

I am experiencing the exception being thrown at connection.Execute

I am fairly new to C# and to coding in general, and I am sorry if I'm unintentionally vague here.

Comment: what you thought is right. you need to convert your image to byte[] before adding it to the parameter. thats all you gonna do. Then when you try to read it back you read it as byte[] and convert it to an Image object.

Comment: Where I am lost is I don't know where I should put that in, should it be on my form.cs under Button_Click or should it go here, and where? I mean I know that placement isn't that critical. However, I am also confused on the format.

Comment: What is the data type of model.ScreenShot?

Comment: I am using class System.Drawing.Image. It reads: public Image ScreenShot { get; set; } should it change?